# Send Data without using form submit from javascript to Laravel 5 controller using Ajax Post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Actually, I've successfully pass data from my javascript to php and updated the database.
However lately, I've been using laravel to develop my own website, and I've been trying to pass my data from javascript to laravel controller, the code looks like below

**ProductController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use DB;

use App\Product;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
       $product = DB::select('select * from feedback');

        return view('pages.addVisit');
       // return view('products.index')
         //   ->with('product',$product);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('products.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
       $rating = new Product;
       $rating->Name= $request->name;
       $rating->save();
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}

if(!empty($_POST['name']))
{
    $output = "<script>console.log( 'this is name');</script>";
    echo $output;
    $obj = new ProductController();
    $obj -> store($_POST['name']);
}
```

MyJavascript
[Here is my js](http://jsbin.com/dipocezehe/edit?html,css,js,output)

So, From what I've learn that the function store accept a post parameter, which is that store should catch my $_POST['name'](because i send to  ProductController.php using ajax post)

the problem I'm facing now is that it seems the ProductController.php didnt receive data that I've pass from my js(i tried to echo some string inside the condition and it didn't show).

I've trying to figure it out for an hour,but it seems nothing wrong
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: you have not define which action you want to hit in ProductController

Answer (score 0):

if you post on store() action then try this

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $formData = Input::All();
   dd($formData);
   // or for single param
   dd($request->input('name'));
}
```

Comment: actually i tried to post name and run the store function after the ProductController.php received the value,

that why  i check if the name is not empty(received), then i create an object to run the store function(because the store function is inside the class)

Comment: you can use Input::All() to get all request data

Comment: in laravel you can get Resquest like shown  in store()  action i dnt understand why you using $_POST['name'] ..?  you can use simply $request->input('name'); to  get request .. for more https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests